# How to animate the height of AbsoluteLayout from 100% to 80% using nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

How to animate the height of AbsoluteLayout from 100% to 80% using nativescript?

Could anyone provide a solution for the above?

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you have already tried. This helps others to assist you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: <StackLayout height="100%"></StackLayout>... How i can animate this height to 80 %.

Comment: Bala, I meant add your sample code to your question...